# install4j: Verifying glibc on Linux platforms

Tags: java, linux, install4j

I am trying to verify the version of `glibc` running on the client machine before installation begins.

So far, I have created an action `Run executable or batch file` just after `Request Privileges`. It is running `/usr/bin/ldd --version | /usr/bin/awk '/ldd/{print $NF}'` (calls ldd --version and extracts the version with awk) and storing it in a variable. I thought maybe after that point, I'd be able to add a validation action but I don't see any.

Am I going about this right? And if so, how would I terminate the installation process with some sort of variable validation action?

Thank you,

Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the "Redirect stdout" property of the "Run executable or batch file" action to "To installer variable", then set the "Installer variable name" property to "glibcVersion".

Then you can add a "Run script" action to examine the value:

```
String version = (String)context.getVariable("glibcVersion");
boolean versionOk = ...;

return versionOk;
```

When you return false, you can quit the installer by setting the "Failure strategy" property of the "Run script" action to "Quit on failure" and enter an error message in the "Error message" property.

Comment: Thank you again Ingo. Big help.